# TPM2 Signature Verification failure tpm2-tools openssl

Tags: openssl, tpm

This flow is giving me

```
Verification failure
809B58AB9D7F0000:error:0200008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding:../crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:75:
809B58AB9D7F0000:error:02000072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:padding check failed:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:599:
809B58AB9D7F0000:error:1C880004:Provider routines:rsa_verify:RSA lib:../providers/implementations/signature/rsa_sig.c:774:
```

when I try to verify the signature signed by the TPM2

Here's my steps

Create a primary key in Endorsement Hierarchy and get it’s public cert

```
tpm2_createprimary --hierarchy e --key-context primary.ctx \
  --format=pem --output=primary.pub.pem
```

Create a subkey for signing and get it’s public cert

```
tpm2_create --key-algorithm rsa --public sub.pub --private sub.priv \
  --parent-context primary.ctx --format pem --output sub.pub.pem
```

Load subkey

```
tpm2_load --parent-context primary.ctx --public sub.pub --private sub.priv \
  --key-context sub.ctx
```

Create hardware info

```
echo "1234-5678" > serial_number
```

Hash the message

```
sha256sum serial_number | awk '{ print "000000: " $1 }' | \
  xxd -r -c 32 > serial_number.hash
```

Sign with the TPM

```
tpm2_sign --key-context sub.ctx --hash-algorithm sha256 --signature serial_number.sig serial_number
```

Verify the signature

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify sub.pub.pem -keyform pem -signature serial_number.sig serial_number
```

It's strange, coz I can encrypt with the public key in openssl and decrypt with the TPM just fine. (and visa versa)

I'm essentially trying to re-create this https://youtu.be/D7h-D1q5fE8?t=1816

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problems are the formats.

You create a sha256-hash `serial_number.hash` and tpm2_sign will hash the content and sign it, so you have `sha256(sha256(content))`.
You can use `--digest` to provide a hash for tpm2_sign or just let `tpm2_sign` hash your message.
Per default `tpm2_sign` creates a signature in the `tss` format, but it is easier to use a plain format with openssl.

These command should work (ecc instead of rsa):

```
tpm2_createprimary -C e -c primary.ctx
tpm2_create -G ecc -u ecc.pub -r ecc.priv -C primary.ctx 
tpm2_load -C primary.ctx -u ecc.pub -r ecc.priv -c ecc.ctx
tpm2_evictcontrol -c ecc.ctx &> evicted
handle="$(awk '/persistent-handle:/ {print $2}' evicted)"
openssl pkey -provider tpm2 -in "handle:${handle}" -pubout -out public_key.pem
openssl ec -outform der -pubin -in public_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.der

# Create and sign message
printf msg1234 > message.dat
tpm2_sign --key-context "${handle}" --hash-algorithm sha256 --scheme ecdsa --format plain --signature sig.der message.dat

# verify with tpm
tpm2_verifysignature --key-context "${handle}" -g sha256 --scheme ecdsa -s sig.der -m message.dat
# verify with openssl 
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA256 -verify public_key.pem -keyform PEM -sha256 -signature sig.der -binary message.dat
```